# How to do a Fluent NHibernate ClassMap join with extra criteria

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm having an issue trying to map a property to another table via a join but with extra criteria. My Code below is for the class I am trying to join from, I basically want to join ServerEventLog property by joining on a TestLog table but searching for a specific Message type id in the process which is defined in the test log table.

```
public class ExecutedTest
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TestLog TestLog { get; set; }

    public virtual TestLog ServerEventLog { get; set; }
}
```

And then the test log class is the class i want to map to

```
public class TestLog
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual string Message { get; set; }

    public virtual int ExecutedTestId { get; set; }
}
```

I can get the SQL to generate something like the following using the class map below.

```
SELECT ...
FROM [ExecutedTest] executedte0_ 
inner join TestLog executedte0_1_ on
  executedte0_.Id=executedte0_1_.ExecutedTestId 
WHERE executedte0_.Id=?

public class ExecutedTestMap : ClassMap<ExecutedTest>
{
    public ExecutedTestMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.TestLog).Column("LogId").Cascade.All();
        this.Join(
            "TestLog",
            x =>
                {
                    x.KeyColumn("ExecutedTestId");

                });
    }
}
```

But what I can't work out is how I get sql to be generated like the following through the join criteria (have highlighted the bit i cant generate inbetween the stared bit).

```
SELECT ...
FROM [ExecutedTest] executedte0_ 
inner join TestLog executedte0_1_ on
  executedte0_.Id=executedte0_1_.ExecutedTestId
  **** and executedte0_1_.MessageTypeId = 9 ****
WHERE executedte0_.Id=?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated if someone knows how to achieve this through the ClassMap. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what Join() is meant for. You could devide Testlog into

```
public virtual EventLog ServerEventLog { get; set; }


public class TestLog
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual string Message { get; set; }
}

public class EventLog : TestLog { }

public class TestLogMap : ClassMap<TestLog>
{
    public TestLogMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.Message, "Message");
        DiscriminateSubclassesOnColumn("MessageTypeId", 1 /*MessageTypeId of TestLog*/);
    }
}

public class EventLogMap : ClassMap<EventLog>
{
    public EventLogMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue(9 /*MessageTypeId of EventLog*/);
    }
}
```

or change the ServerEventLog to a Collection

```
// in ExecutedTestMap
HasMany(x => x.ServerEventLogs)
    .KeyColumn("ExecutedTestId")
    .Where("ExecutedTestId")
    .KeyColumn("MessageTypeId = 9");
```